# Limit for creating stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have a need of creating more than 5000 stores in a month.
How many stores can we create in Magento 1.9? Is there any limit?

Comment: It should only be limited by Database size, at least I have not heard of any specific limit otherwise.

Comment: I am curious - what are you trying to do, and why did you design it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento have no technical limit to create stores, but you have the problem, that magento creates a price index which is based on:

- websites
- customer groups
- products
- tax_classes

So when you create only store views, you don't get a problem here. If you create websites, your index will explode when you only have a few products because:

```
# websites * # customer groups * # products * # tax classes
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian for your valuable answer. I will have about 50 to 60 products. Do you think it is still a problem?

Comment: How much customer groups and tax classes do you have? Do you have websites or only store views?

Comment: For now I have no requirement for creating new customer groups and new tax classes. And I will be having sub domains.

Comment: Not only that, but it will have significant performance impact in many other parts of yor store. This includes the search index, initializing cache, etc. etc. For more than 100 stores, I definitely don't recommend using websites or storeviews, you will need to write something custom.

Comment: Daniel, you should add this as a second answer!

Comment: To give you an example: we had a client with 400-500 storeviews. While the problems are not impossible to solve, we had to patch Magento in a lot of areas to make it performant enough. I don't even want to know what would happen with 5000 stores per month.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I think your comment answers it enough, I just wanted to give the same answer from a different perspective :-P

Comment: Exactly that is a second answer :p And it raises legally the question:answer ratio :D

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem I experianced for such a big number of store views are product attributes and related to this the product import.

Rule 1 for so many storeviews: disable the category and product flat tables. Maybe only in system cobfig is not enough, I saw some actions trigger the index even if it is not used, so maybe you need to rewrite some classes and make method calls empty.

If you have a lot of product attributes, you maybe want to maintain them over a seperate table to improve speed of import actions to a acceptable level.
Especially if you have a lot of attributes who are the same between storeviews, as you can build an improved lookup logic.

For search you want to use an external solution like solr or elastic search anyway.

Maybe even disable to include the category path in product url, else you have a lot of additional entries there.

Another point, have a person who is complete dedicated to configure your mysql setup. Use the most current mysql (5.6), use ssd and no virtualisation for mysql.

And think about why you have so many storeviews and think about how you maybe could cheat to reduce them(often they are used because of translations)

In the end, you can use Magento for this many storeviews, but a lot of features are not usable like initialy intended

Also I wrote a while ago about such issues, not the final truth, maybe some parts wrong, but hope it helps anyway.

http://flyingmana.de/blog_en/2013/10/02/Magento_performance_related_architecture.html